# Get Instagram profile page from an id

Tags: swift, api, instagram-api, factual

I have been using Factual Places & Crosswalk API to get Social Media links on some specific places on my iOS app. The `API` returns proper links for Facebook & Twitter. But for Instagram it just return an `id`, something like this `79471948`.

I was wondering how I can make use of this `id`. I thought I could use it in a `URL`, something like this. **http://instagram.com/79471948**, But this does not exists.

Then I thought the `id` could be a `user-id`. If it is a `user-id` I wanna get the `username` of the corresponding `user-id` so that I open his profile page something like this **http://instagram.com/79471948**. But as we know that `Instagram` does not allow us to directly request for User Data without `OAuth` we can't get access token. Without getting access token, I cant get the `username`.

So do you guys have any suggestions? So the whole thing is, I have this id `79471948` and I wanna open up the corresponding profile without doing any OAuth.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use API to get the user profile from user-id.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

https://www.picodash.com/@ allows you to search for a `user-id` and view the full profile or open actual `instagram.com/username` link and view.

[image]

Comment: Hi Krisrak, thanks for reply but still i did not get the profile
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/39605868/media/recent/?access_token=myaccesstoken.   
gives error like "this user does not exist"

Comment: either that user does not exist or that user is private, instagram API does not allow accessing private user data even if u follow or are approved by that user

Comment: Actually i get the id from Factual api. example place info is https://www.factual.com/037e34dc-16d2-4a00-ab31-c863523be511

How could i show profile page from Instagram_place ID?

Comment: that id is not same as instagram location id, its not that simple, you have to search for the place name in facebook place api and use the facebook place id to get instagram location id, and then make instagram api to get location feed. Picodash has this implemented.